# Check surrounding patch colors in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

How would I go about checking the patch colors of the patches that are above, below, to the left and to the right of each patch? I know I would embed it in a ask patches [ insert code here ] statement, but I don't know what to put in that ask statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ask the turtles to show the colors of the 4 patches around each one of them just

```
ask turtles [show [pcolor] of neighbors4]
```

Comment: You are correct Jose, I forgot to update my Stack post. To anyone else who needs this help, You can use neighbors4 for neighbors above/below and left/right or neighbors for all 8 neighbors. Thanks though Jose!